# OpenCV from command line in windows

Tags: opencv, cmd, template-matching

I try to extend some MonkeyRunner script to automate some android app testing. One thing I need now is some kind of image template matching (find image location in bigger image). As MonkeyRunner uses some old Jython version I found it impossible to use opencv/cv2 python modules in it.
My idea now was to execute from jython code some command line tool which does the template matching.

I think it should be possible to do it but I could not find a way to launch opencv from command line directly.

Can somebody give me a hint where to find such information? Or, if you know some other tool which is easy to use from command line and can do template matching, i would also take hints about those tools.
Thanks!

Comment: "launch opencv from command line" -- OpenCV is a library, so as such you can't "launch" it. You need to write some application using it, and then you'll have something to "launch". | Note that "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow"

Comment: sure but I thought there is probably some kind of cmd wrapper for it available which I don't find

Comment: cmd wrapper for what?!? Can you give an example of other libraries that provide such a wrapper? Do you mean something like ffmpeg?